# Map rendering many small tiles instead of one large single one

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am creating a map that consists of three maps and markers total that can be switched between [like in this leaflet example](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/), although when I test it, instead of the each map rendering as a single version filling the map frame they display as many multiple in a tile layout. Below is my code I am currently using, note that the images I am using for the maps are not actually maps thus I am using the 'L.CRS.Simple'.

[This is the result I was expecting](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/example.html) (sans the makers and with my images), maybe someone can spot where I went wrong?

-

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Interactive Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ==" crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log==" crossorigin=""></script>
    <style>
        #map {
            width: 1000px;
            height: 1000px;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="map">
     <script>

        var map1 = L.tileLayer('map1.png');
        var map2 = L.tileLayer('map2.png');
        var map3 = L.tileLayer('map3.png');

        var markers = L.layerGroup(); //Leaving empty for the time being, using just to create check box in menu

        var map = L.map('map', {
            crs: L.CRS.Simple,
            layers: [map1, map2, map3, markers],
            maxZoom: 5
        });

        var baseMaps = {
            "Map 1": map1, 
            "Map 2": map2, 
            "Map 3": map3
        };

        var overlayMaps = {
            "Markers": markers
        };

        var bounds = [[0,0], [1000,1000]];
        L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, bounds).addTo(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

    </script>
    </div>
</body>
```

Yes, I am using locally stored images, no, I do not have images setup to use the standard URL format, if you choose to try my code just sub in 3 random pictures.

Here is a pic of what is occurring:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a 's' to markers

```
var overlayMaps = {
        "Markers": markers
    };
```

It should work now ;)

Comment: Unfortunately though that did fix the immediate issue of it not working, it did not fix my original problem. I've added a picture of what is occurring to my original post (as well as added the 's' to marker).